# Understanding Scala Syntax

Tags: scala, default-parameters, default-arguments

I have code below and I wanted to know what does `Seq[String] = List()` mean?
Does it mean it takes sequence of strings and converts it into `List()`?

```
def somefuncname(input: Seq[String] = List()): Unit = {
  //Some Code
}
```

Comment: Please first read some tutorial, see https://www.scala-lang.org/

Comment: [Default parameter values](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/default-parameter-values.html).

Comment: You can play around in [ScalaFiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/): put this into your method: println(input), and call 
somefuncname() and 
somefuncname(List("1","2","3")). If you remove the = List() if wont compile when you call it without arguments

Answer (score 2):

First try to understand the below function signature.

```
def somefuncname(input: Seq[String]): Unit = {
  //Some Code
}
```

The above code is a function declaration. Its a function which takes 1 argument called `input` which is of type `Seq[String]`. That means it takes sequence or list of strings as input and returns nothing `Unit`

Now, what does `=` mean?

`=` after the input argument of the function means `default value` for the function argument. If you are not interested in passing a custom "sequence of strings" then you can rely on the default argument of already passed.

Now, what does `List()` mean?

`List()` returns sequence of 0 elements or empty sequence. That means function is taking empty elements as default argument

alternatively you can also pass `Seq()` as default argument. It also means empty sequence

```
def somefuncname(input: Seq[String] = Seq()): Unit = {
 //Some Code
}
```

Now to use the function in any of the following ways

1. `somefuncname()` // Now `input` is empty sequence of strings
2. `somefuncname(Seq("apple", "cat"))`
3. `somefuncname(List("apple", "cat"))`

Answer (score 1):

input is of type Seq[String] and it has a default value of empty list (List()).
Having a default value means so that if you call the function without passing an argument it would get the default value